# Реально ли ограничить версию либы в рамках одного модуля не перекидывая при этом версию на соседние

Tags: maven, модули, зависимости

Есть мультимодульный проект, проектная версия *джексона* очень старая. В одном из модулей понадобилось подключить **либу**, которой нужен новый *джексон*. Естественно, просто взять и подключить эту версию для модуля я не могу, ибо **тогда новая версия джексона распространится на соседние модули**. Даунгрейднуть либу не выйдет - самая старая версия пользует слишком новый джексон. Апгрейднуть проектную версию джексона тоже не вариант - не позволят.
Какие возможны пути решения таких моментов. Возможно ли, чтобы **именно эта либа пользовалась одной версией джексона, а в остальном проекте осталась старая**.
Или возможно ли, чтобы **именно этот модуль пользовался новым джексоном, не перекидывая версии на соседние модули**.

Или же вообще какой-нибудь иной подход решения такого момента.

Comment: Использовать платформу эклипс с его загрузчиком. Он позволяет загружать разные версии библиотек. Но это приведёт к бОльшим изменениям в проекте, нежели вы перепишите проект под новую версию библиотеки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобравшись в проблеме заключил, что способов решить такое, учитывая мои запросы просто нет. В любом случае на проект должна быть одна версия библиотеки, поэтому для общих случаев наиболее подходящих варианта 2. 
1 - Переписать весь проект под новую библиотеку, что в рамках моего проекта не представлялось возможным. 
2 - Поискать аналог добавляемой библиотеки, которая либо использует нужную версию джексона, либо не использует его в принципе. 
Остановился я в итоге на втором варианте и переписал имеющуюся реализацию.
Библиотека, о которой шла речь - Java JWT, как альтернативу взял Nimbus JOSE+JWT, которая работает через другой сериализатор.